# How can I improve the performance of database updates from Java?

Tags: java, sql, database

I currently have a Java thread to update the database once every few seconds. The database is MSSQL 2005, Java version is 6.0.

There are approximately 800 updates every time. So what I did was `setAutoCommit(false)` in the biginning and call `commit()` after 800 `executeUpdate()` calls. These takes about 500ms.

I also tried using batch mode, and the improvement is marginal. It takes about 250ms now.

Is there any way I can improve it? 250ms still seems too slow.

The server and the client are in the same data center, latency should be minimum.

Comment: Do you use any connection pool implementation, or straight from `DriverManager`? If not you can try http://proxool.sourceforge.net/ or http://jolbox.com/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/

Comment: Marginal? It's **twice** as fast! How large is the data? Does that time take connection time and network latency into account?

Comment: 250ms doesn't sound too bad for 800 updates.

Comment: Just to make sure: You did use a PreparedStatement for this instead of recreating a new Statement for each call, did you?

Comment: Yes i am using prepared statement

Answer (score 4):

You don't explain what you're trying to do, so it's hard to suggest improvements.

One thing you might try is restructuring your dbms schema so you can INSERT rather than UPDATE these rows every few seconds.  That should help somewhat.  You might be able to use an hourly or overnight DELETE operation to clean out the older data.

Another thing might be to figure out how to structure the data so you're handling fewer than 800 rows.  Can you put multiple data items together in a single row.  That would let you update fewer rows.

It has to be said, 800 updates in a quarter second is not horrible performance.

Comment: ++ Exactly right on that point. Also..do you have unnecessary indexes? Are you using direct SQL or using PreparedStatements? Do you need larger buffer pools or page sizes in your database? Too hard to state without explaining what it is your are doing and why as Ollie Jones mentioned. Also..you may want to check out the DBA site (dba.stackexchange.com). I've gotten some really useful answers there from the guys who know databases best - the DBA's.

Comment: Is update statement so costly? i have no idea... doing insert of 800 rows should be much faster right?

Comment: An update statement has to read, modify, and write a table, and potentially update indexes.  It has to do so with some kind of transactional integrity. inserts don't need to read or modify, but they do need the rest.  the dbms can defer some of the work of the inserts.  None of this would be a big problem if you were just doing a few of them. But you're doing a lot.